# MySQL , PHP Issues With Date() and Now()

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application in PHP , MySQL for a client wherein the dates and times have a major role to play.

Now the issue is that in all my MySQL tables, I am using `DATETIME()` types to store date/time and if i compare the dates using php's date function and the data inserted using MySQL's `NOW()` function , there is a major difference .

For instance:

```
INSERt INTO sales_session (userid,start_time) 
       VALUES ('".$_SESSION['active_userid']."',NOW())
```

In the above query , the start_time is stored as **2015-02-20 22:42:08**

If I want to make some checks/calculates/comparison between the current time and the start time , I face major issues because i am using PHP's date function to do so .

So my current time is `$current_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` which shows 
**2015-02-21 05:45:41**

I really want to know how to deal with this as `$current_time` in PHP shows a completely different time than MySQL's `NOW()`.

Thanks.

Comment: so the issue was not timezone? How date format could fix the issue? I think I did not understood the question

Comment: is the time difference an exact number of hours? Is the hosting server in a different country to your location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`"); //LIMIT 1 MAYBE 4 SECURITY
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
//output: 2015-02-21 07:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y H:i:s');
//output: 21/02/2015 07:45:12

echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
//output: 21/02/15

echo date_format($date, 'g:i A');
//output: 7:45 PM

echo date_format($date, 'G:ia');
//output: 07:45pm

echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
//output: 7:45pm on Saturday 21st February 2015

?>
```

more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

to compare maybe use unix timestamp

more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP date uses system date/time in order to change the tie you need to adjust your timezone:

- Open your php.ini file
- Add the following line of code to top of your php.ini file

  `date.timezone = "US/Central"`

List of supported time zones: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

if you don't have access to your php.ini you can change it with PHP function `date_default_timezone_set`

**Read**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Or you can change it with .htaccess file:
`SetEnv TZ America/Chicago`

**Read**: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/setting-server-timezone/